# Assign all classes in a package as a maven variable

Tags: java, xml, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I am using a Java [ServiceLoader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) to dynamically load all the classes which are extended from an Abstract Class (`AbstractDeathHandler`). Currently, every time I create a new implementation I have to add the reference into my `resources/META-INF/services/...` file. After much research I was unable to come up with any real solutions. It would be very useful if it were possible to set a Maven variable that could generate this list while compiling.

Relevant `pom.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

This is the file I want to be able to use a Maven variable with `resources/META-INF/services/com.jordanschnur.deathmessagesplus.handlers.AbstractDeathHandler`:

```
com.jordanschnur.deathmessagesplus.handlers.EntityDeathExplosionHandler
com.jordanschnur.deathmessagesplus.handlers.EntityAttackEntityHandler
com.jordanschnur.deathmessagesplus.handlers.FallHandler
```

Is it possible to define something like `${project.handlers}` as all the files in this package?

Comment: There is no way with default Maven to handle such case. It sounds like that could a candidate to implement maven plugin which handles that..

Comment: I was worried that would be the case. Thank you.